# Can I answer my own bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I started a bounty which has no answers yet.
Can I answer my own question and award myself the reputation back?

IMO it's also a problem of the site that I open a bounty and get no response/answers, only losing my reputation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Think of the bounty like of taking out an ad in the newspaper. The money for the ad is also not refundable if you don't gain any customers.

Comment: But if you have a good answer to your question, even if you don't win back the Bounty. You can win some reputation by providing a good answer to the community. But rep should not be an issue once you

Comment: I feel like you should be able to get your bounty back if you come up with your own solution.

Comment: Maybe there could be a minimum of positive votes for when someone answers their own question. And then the reputation could be awarded, or "refunded", if you wish.

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo funny that I just answer my own bounty again and I probably choose other answer
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456982/onceperrequestfilter-unable-to-set-error-code-different-than-404

Comment: well, if there is a better answer, that's no problem. Mine hasn't... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978377/how-to-avoid-pycharm-console-crash-warning-qapplication-was-not-created-in-the

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. While you can certainly answer your own question and accept your answer, you cannot award the bounty to yourself, nor could you earn half of the bounty through the auto-award for an answer with a score of 2 or greater.

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. **(You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)**

See also:

- [Meta FAQ: How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/21960)